# appending text to a file. %s f.name

Tags: python, text, filenames

```
import os

def closed(x):
        if f.closed == True:
                return "closed"
        else:
                return "open"

f = open("test.txt", "ab")
print "Name of the file: ", f.name
print "we just opened the file so the file is: ", closed(f)
f.write("I am writing now to the file %s \n") % (f.name)
f.close()
print "now we typed f.close(), so it is: ", closed(f)
```

It gives me error, and prints out to test.txt the %s and doesn't understand %s? why?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "attempt1.py", line 12, in 
    f.write("I am writing now to the file %s \n") % (f.name)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'

I want it to write "I am writing now to the file test.txt" using the %s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not formatting the string correctly, fix this line:

```
f.write("I am writing now to the file %s \n" % f.name)
```

On your code, you closed the parenthesis leaving the string unformatted and with a SyntaxError since `% (f.name)` is not valid Python.

By the way, that kind of formatting is been improved with [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iterator#str.format). Something like this:

```
f.write("I am writing now to the file {} \n".format(f.name))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your % is outside of print try

```
f.write("I am writing now to the file %s \n" % f.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Paulo Bu's answer, file handling has also improved.
I'm talking about [Context Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html).
They automatically call `.close()` on your managed object for you.

Here's how your snippet would look like:

```
import os

with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
    print("Name of the file:", f.name)
    f.write("I am writing now to the file {} \n".format(f.name))
```

Furthermore, you'll notice I removed the `"b"` from `open()`'s `mode` parameter.
It looks like you're just appending text, not binary data, so that `"b"` doesn't make sense.
Have a looksee here ([python's built-in open function docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)) at the flags you can pass to `mode` and what they mean.